# default for serialized column in activerecord migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

so i have a serialized column :dimensions, and in my migration, i would like to set the field to be a default hash.

i have tried...

```
create_table :shipping_profiles do |t|
      t.string      :dimensions_in, :default => {:width => 0, :height => 0, :depth => 0}
```

and just

```
t.string :dimensions_in, :default => Hash.new()
```

but the fields end up null.  how can i set a default serialized object for this field on creation, or at least make sure my serialize attribute is always a hash?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When Rails serializes a hash to save in the db, all it does is convert it to YAML so that it can be stored as a string. To get this to work in the migration, all you need to do is convert the hash to yaml...

```
t.string :dimensions_in, :default => {:width => 0, :height => 0, :depth => 0}.to_yaml
```

Or, alternatively, set it in the model after initialization...

```
class ShippingProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_initialize :set_default_dimensions

  private

    def set_default_dimensions
      self.dimensions_in ||= {:width => 0, :height => 0, :depth => 0}
    end

end
```

Comment: great to know about the yaml trick in migrations as well, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately in my case this won't work. I'm using MySQL and a text field type and the combination won't support a default value.

Comment: Be wary of after_initialize solutions as you might incur significant performance overhead when instantiating lots of objects such as from an ActiveRecord finder query. The most performant approach is to overwrite the accessor as detailed by @DragonStar - although see my comment to get it to work for serialized attributes.

Answer (score 8):

You can also specify a default class for the serialized column. See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays,+hashes,+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns).

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :dimensions_in, Hash
end
```

I've found that **after_initialize** blocks can cause a **huge performance hit**, especially if you would ever need to `MyModel.all` (eg: for a bulk export)

Without the class: `MyModel.new.dimensions_in => nil`

With a default Hash class: `MyModel.new.dimensions_in => {}`

Comment: But how to pass default values through this method?

Comment: @ZuhaibAli From the docs: "the default value for that attribute will be a new instance of that class." So with this method it is only a new instance and cannot be something custom.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this code and it worked for me.  This takes advantage of the way ActiveRecord sends model methods synced to table columns dynamically.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def dimensions_in
    attributes["dimensions_in"] ||= {:width => 0, :height => 0, :depth => 0}
  end

end
```

Comment: Great! Can be used as default value without specifying default in migration

Comment: this doesn't work with attributes that are serialized such as `serialize :dimensions_in, Hash` as the attribute comes back as the object type and thus is "present". You'll need to do something like `attributes['dimensions_in'].present? ? attributes['dimensions_in'] : {width: 0, height: 0, depth: 0}`