# Rails serialization with default value and new objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, serialization

Yet another rails [serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) question. I've read a lot of these and couldn't find the answer to my problem, so here it is:

I have the typical:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :prefs, Hash
```

In my migrations (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943435/default-for-serialized-column-in-activerecord-migration#answer-4943878) question+answer):

```
add_column :user, :prefs, :text, default: { foo: 'bar' }.to_yaml
```

Now, when I load an existing user :prefs gets deserialized:

```
User.first.prefs[:foo] # returns 'bar'
User.first.prefs.class # returns Hash
User.first.prefs       # returns {:foo => "bar"}
```

So it works perfect! But when I create a new one:

```
User.new.prefs[:foor]  # TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
User.new.prefs.class   # returns String
User.new.prefs         # returns "---\n:foo: bar\n"
```

Is it possible to get this working without any of these?

- `after_initialize :method`
- a gem like [default_value_for](http://rubygems.org/gems/default_value_for)
- overriding `initialize`

I really want to get it working with only the database default. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What database adapter are you using?

Comment: I'm using [this](https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter) one.. Mmm.. I'll check if it happens without it.

Comment: I works fine with pg (0.14.0) and activerecord-postgis-adapter (0.4.3) adapters for me. However, it's not working with sqlite3 (1.3.6) adapter. That's why I was asking for the adapater you are using because it may have to do something with it or it's version. In case of sqlite3, I think there's bug in parsing column default if column default contains newline character (\n). I was checking on latest ruby (1.9.2-p194) + rails (3.2.6) stack.

Comment: @mdominiak  Thanks for your help! I'm using ruby 1.9.3p125 and tried with rails 3.2.5 and 3.2.6... I tried with other models in this project and got the same result. But in a new project it worked.. I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never found out what was causing this behaviour to fail, but everything works with Rails 3.2.13. Using `serialize :prefs, Hash`:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.new
=> #<User id: nil, prefs: {:foo=>"bar"}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(main)> User.new.prefs
=> {:foo=>"bar"}
```

And using `store :prefs, accessors: [:foo]`:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.new
=> #<User id: nil, prefs: {:foo=>"bar"}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(main)> User.new.foo
=> "bar"
```

My migration is:

```
add_column :user, :prefs, :text, default: { foo: 'bar' }.to_yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

When I did the following in the Rails console (Rails 3.2.6, Ruby 1.9.3-p194):

```
u=User.new(:prefs=>{:foo2=>"bar2"})
```

I got back:

```
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, prefs: {:foo2=>"bar2"}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

So I think this is the syntax you want.

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I don't want to set up defaults whenever I create a new User. I want defaults in the database schema.